# Working with dates in tsql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, select

I want to create a report that gives me a total for sales by month so

```
select customer,month(dated), sum(invtotal)
from salestable
group by customer,dated
```

gives me the my result but I get multiple lines returned if a customer had three orders for a particular month.

I was expecting the month(dated) to strip out the day part of the date and just return everything for a particular month as one whole, it does not appear to do that.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should `GROUP BY  customer, MONTH(dated)`. Perhaps add date year as well, if your data spans multiple years.

Answer (score 5):

```
select    customer, month(dated), sum(invtotal)
  from salestable
 group by customer, month(dated)
```

Comment: My issue is that if I have several lines whic are all dated within December I still return those lines whereas I want a total for the month...I was hoping by using month(date) it would give me figures for November, December and January on three lines instead I am still getting the same number of rows as the actual data....

Comment: Really?   I don't think you are using the answer i posted.

Comment: Your query is too long?   This is the answer to the short query you posted as a question.   Does the query in my answer above work or not?

Comment: your query works perfectly - thanks. but I only posted up a summary of my sql query and something in my actual query is still giving me an issue - I think it is down to the month(date) - how can I post my full query on here so you can see it?

Comment: SO is not free coding service.  You posted a problem query and got a fix.